# Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity

Tags: java, android, back-button

I've noticed this pattern in a lot of Android apps and games recently: when clicking the back button to "exit" the application, a `Toast` comes up with a message similar to "Please click BACK again to exit".

I was wondering, as I'm seeing it more and more often, is that a built-in feature that you can somehow access in an activity? I've looked at the source code of many classes but I can't seem to find anything about that.

Of course, I can think about a few ways to achieve the same functionality quite easily (the easiest is probably to keep a boolean in the activity that indicates whether the user already clicked once...) but I was wondering if there's something already here.

**EDIT**: As @LAS_VEGAS mentioned, I didn't really mean "exit" in the traditional meaning. (i.e. terminated) I meant "going back to whatever was open before the application start activity was launched", if that makes sense :)

Comment: [Android - Confirm app exit with toast]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006461/android-confirm-app-exit-with-toast/18654014#18654014

Comment: I had the same problem when using the HoloEverywhere Library, too simply you can add android:launchMode="singleTask" to you activity definition in the manifest file.

Comment: Other solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clicking on the android back button twice to exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581427/clicking-on-the-android-back-button-twice-to-exit-the-app)

Answer (score 1067, accepted):

> In Java Activity:

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
        
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

> In Kotlin Activity:

```
private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed()
            return
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(Runnable { doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false }, 2000)
    }
```

I Think this handler helps to reset the variable after 2 second.

Comment: Best answer! You may also add condition 
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce || fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
in case of Fragment-based add

Comment: I agree, this is definitely the best answer and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You should remove the Runnable when exit application.

Comment: Check my answer.I have modified the answer given by `Sudheesh B Nair` to cover the above suggested comments.

Comment: It's a nice quick solution/answer but I **don't** agree that it's the *best solution*. And for the ones who think this will be *best answer*  again I can't agree. These solution causes **leaks** and will require extra effort for handling. Check the *aswers* below for further details.

Comment: @Zefnus, Why ? Please explain for the beginners like me.

Comment: @partho you shouldn't just register a callback to a handler and forget all about the rest. It will cause a leak when you don't need the handler anymore. You should rather remove the callback and manage handler lifecycle in order to prevent leaks. An easier and more optimized solution without handler usage is described below. Please check my answer and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: if i add this code block me getting error  in handler

Comment: Handler must be handled with care now. If user presses back, it might leak.

Comment: I personally like using a [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar) instead of a Toast. The Toast persists on the screen for some extra time after the app is closed despite using `LENGTH_SHORT`

Comment: This is not good solution. Get the System currentMillisecons everytime on each back press and check the difference with previous System currentMillisecons fetched. You can also set the milliseconds to allow next backpress for finishing activity. This is very robust approach. Or else, you can also use Snackbar to prompt user to exit (but that's not recommended as per UX guidelines). In order to prompt for exit, use AlertDialog specifically.

Answer (score 255):

[Sudheesh B Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity/13578600#13578600)'s has a nice (and accepted) answer on the question, which i think should have a better alternative such as;

What's wrong with measuring time passed and checking if `TIME_INTERVAL` miliseconds (say 2000) passed since the last back press. The following sample code uses `System.currentTimeMillis();` to store the time `onBackPressed()` is called;

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; // # milliseconds, desired time passed between two back presses.
private long mBackPressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
    { 
        super.onBackPressed(); 
        return;
    }
    else { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

---

Back on accepted answer *critique*; Using a **`flag`** to indicate if it was pressed in last `TIME_INTERVAL` (say 2000) milliseconds and *set - reset* is via `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` method was the first thing to come in my mind. But the `postDelayed()` action should be cancelled when activity is closing, removing the `Runnable`.

In order to remove the `Runnable`, it must not be declared *anonymous*, and be declared as member along with the `Handler` aswell. Then `removeCallbacks()` method of `Handler` can be called appropriately.

The following sample is the demonstration;

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;                       
    }
};

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() 
{ 
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mHandler != null) { mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable); }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
}
```

---

Thanks to @NSouth for contributing; In order to prevent *toast message* appearing even after the application is closed, `Toast` can be declared as a member - say `mExitToast` - and can be cancelled via `mExitToast.cancel();` just before `super.onBackPressed();` call.

Comment: For the ones who think that it's the same what Sudheesh B Nair said: Same functionality, better performance. so +1.

Comment: I like this answer and I think it's the best. I mean i don't THINK it is, IT IS the best answer, for the reasons stated above. I hope you get more upvotes for this one. One comment though: no one finds it a it odd that the toast persists a couple of seconds after the app closes? No one cares to cancel the toast? I know it may be a small detail but I think that should happen. What do you guys think?

Comment: @acrespo Thank you. You are right, it looks odd when toast continues to appear after application is terminated. Maybe most of the users don't care because it happens. In Android, toast messages appear in launcher and it is usual.

Comment: @joonty thanks for edit, that **int** keyword has been missing for some time. It will compile now (:

Comment: This crashed for me because mHandler was never assigned. I declared it with `private Handler mHandler = new Handler()` and it works fine now. I'm somewhat new to Handlers, so I hope that's a correct implementation.

Comment: @NSouth Second code block was a sample using mHandlers in order to show it required more effort. I suggest you consider using the first code block, which doesn't use a handler.

Comment: @NSouth Thank you for your attempt to add value to the answer with your _rejected_ edit. I have reviewed the content you added, and included it in my answer.

Comment: @acrespo I suppose we have a solid solution for _toast message persisting after the application closes_ now.

Comment: @Zefnus : Don't you think that my answer is almost same as yours? I couldn't find any significant reason to add new one.

Comment: @MehulJoisar Did you read the entire answer? I wanted to make clear that the solution i suggest is the *first code block*, without handler. Solution without handler is not same as your solution in anyway as it uses handler - which is not a short nor simple solution for the issue. Your answer doesn't explain the pitfalls of handler and why you remove them aswell.

Comment: @Zefnus Thanks for the amazing answer. If I want to click the back button 3 times or 5 times to exit the app. How can I implement it? (Just curious. I know the user will have bad experience)

Comment: Now that's the kind of answer I really appreciate. Very well explained and works efficiently! +1 for the extra thought!

Comment: Shouldn't `mBackPressed` be initialized?

Comment: Since this answer is arguably better than the accepted answer, I'd like to echo [Anton's comment on the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity#comment19046108_13578600): "*You may also add condition `if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {` in case of Fragment-based add*"

Comment: This is a best answer

Comment: @SrikarReddy - recipe for changing any code from boolean flag to a counter:  Add `const int REQUIRED_COUNT = 3;`  Replace `boolean pressedOnce` with `int count = 0`. Replace `pressedOnce = false` with `count = 0`. Replace `pressedOnce = true` with `pressedOnce += 1`. Replace `if (pressedOnce)` with `if (counter >= REQUIRED_COUNT)`.

Comment: the first block is simple and best solution

Comment: this answer is the best +1

Answer (score 31):

Just thought I would share how I did it in the end, I just added in my activity:

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.exit_press_back_twice_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And it just works exactly as I want. Including the reset of the state whenever the activity is resumed.

Comment: With this solution the two back presses can have an arbitrary amount of time between them. So you can press `Back` once and then press `Back` again a minute later and the application will exit. This is not the behaviour that the user will expect.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste.

In this case you notify the user just once, so the user knows he is in the main activity and another back press will exit the app (problably after the user has pressed back a couple of times to go back to the main screen). If, later, the user presses back again, we can suppose he wants to exit the app (unless he has navigated into another activities and problably lost track of how deep he got).

In the accepted answer above, you consider that the user might forget that he is already in the main screen.

Both are fine, depending on what you want or consider.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch - I disagree. This is not merely a matter of taste. If significant time has passed, we *should* assume that the user has done other actions in the meantime, and no longer considers what he did previously **and chose not to continue with** to apply. Indeed, all but the most exceptional user will not even still have it in his mind that he previously did that. Without a time limit, you have left the app **in an invisible mode** that the user has no way of knowing about. I absolutely consider that to be poor user interface design. Users will be surprised.

Comment: IMHO, better variants on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14006485/199364) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15728990/199364).

Answer (score 28):

**Process Flow Diagram:**
[image: Press again to exit.]

**Java Code:**

```
private long lastPressedTime;
private static final int PERIOD = 2000;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (event.getDownTime() - lastPressedTime < PERIOD) {
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press again to exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lastPressedTime = event.getEventTime();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I initally voted this as being helpful. Trouble is, for some reason, this doesn't work on some handsets. The onBackPressed method works best, but then you don't have the timestamps, so you need the handlers as the accepted answer states.

Answer (score 28):

There is very simplest way among all these answers.

Simply write following code inside `onBackPressed()` method.

```
long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

You need to define `back_pressed` object as `long` in activity.

Answer (score 18):

You may use a snackbar instead of a toast, so you can rely on their visibility to decide whether to close the app or not. Take this example:

```
Snackbar mSnackbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.press_back_again, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mSnackbar.isShown()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mSnackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Simple, effective, no risk.

Comment: Out of box solution. (clap)

Comment: Simple and Great!! But this affect on all navigation back button!

Answer (score 13):

Based upon the correct answer and suggestions in comments, I have created a demo which works absolutely fine and removes the handler callbacks after being used.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mehuljoisar.d_pressbacktwicetoexit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long delay = 2000L;
    private boolean mRecentlyBackPressed = false;
    private Handler mExitHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mExitRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRecentlyBackPressed=false;   
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //You may also add condition if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce || fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) // in case of Fragment-based add
        if (mRecentlyBackPressed) {
            mExitHandler.removeCallbacks(mExitRunnable);
            mExitHandler = null;
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else
        {
            mRecentlyBackPressed = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mExitHandler.postDelayed(mExitRunnable, delay);
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Are you certain removing handler in `onBackPressed()` fix the _memory leak_ issue?

Comment: @Zefnus : It will fix as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong. How did you trace memory issue with above code?

Answer (score 11):

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
```

**Declare Variable**`private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;`

> Paste this in your Main Activity and this will solve your issue

Answer (score 10):

It is not a good idea to use a Runnable when exit the application, I recently figure out a much simpler way to record and compare the period between two BACK button clicks. Sample code as following:

```
private static long back_pressed_time;
private static long PERIOD = 2000;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        if (back_pressed_time + PERIOD > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

This will do the trick  to exit the application  by a double BACK button clicks within a certain delay period which is 2000 millisecond in sample.

Answer (score 8):

The Accepted answer is Best one but if you are using **[`Android Design Support Library`](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)** then you can use `SnackBar` for Better Views.

```
   boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.photo_album_parent_view), "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not a built in functionality. I think it is not even the recommended behavior. Android apps are not meant to exit:

[Why dont Android applications provide an "Exit" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439978/why-dont-android-applications-provide-an-exit-option)

Comment: Point taken. By exit, I meant "going back to home screen"

Comment: Still it is not a built in functionality. However I'm unaware of any guideline against this. As an android user, I like such functionality.

Answer (score 6):

[Zefnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22332291/1039555)'s answer using System.currentTimeMillis() is the best one (+1). The way I did it is **not** better than that, but still posting it to add to the above ideas.

If the toast is not visible when the back button is pressed, the toast is displayed, whereas, if it is visible (back has already been pressed once within the last `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` time), then it exits.

```
exitToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
.
.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (exitToast.getView().getWindowToken() == null) //if toast is currently not visible
      exitToast.show();  //then show toast saying 'press againt to exit'
   else {                                            //if toast is visible then
      finish();                                      //or super.onBackPressed();
      exitToast.cancel();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is a good way to do this, but if you have more toast messages is not.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul No, this code only checks the status of that specific toast. So any other toasts won't affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Recently, I needed to implement this back button feature in an app of mine. The answers on the original question were useful, but I had to take two more points into consideration:

1. At some points in time, the back button is disabled
2. The main activity is using fragments in combination with a back stack

Based on the answers and comments, I created the following code:

```
private static final long BACK_PRESS_DELAY = 1000;

private boolean mBackPressCancelled = false;
private long mBackPressTimestamp;
private Toast mBackPressToast;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do nothing if the back button is disabled.
    if (!mBackPressCancelled) {
        // Pop fragment if the back stack is not empty.
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            if (mBackPressToast != null) {
                mBackPressToast.cancel();
            }

            long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (currentTimestamp < mBackPressTimestamp + BACK_PRESS_DELAY) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                mBackPressTimestamp = currentTimestamp;

                mBackPressToast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.warning_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mBackPressToast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that the support library is used. If you use fragments but not the support library, you want to replace `getSupportFragmentManager()` by `getFragmentManager()`.

Remove the first `if`, if the back button is never cancelled. Remove the second `if`, if you don`t use fragments or a fragment back stack

Also, it is important to be aware that the method `onBackPressed` is supported since Android 2.0. Check [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for an elaborate description. To make the back press feature work on older versions as well, add the following method to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Declare a global Toast variable for MainActivity Class. example: Toast exitToast;
2. Initialize it in onCreate view method. example:
    exitToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press back again to  exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
3. Finally create a onBackPressedMethod as Follows:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

       if (exitToast.getView().isShown()) {
           exitToast.cancel();
           finish();
       } else {
           exitToast.show();
       }
   }
   ```

This works correctly, i have tested. and I think this is much simpler.

Answer (score 6):

**In  java**

```
private Boolean exit = false; 

if (exit) {
onBackPressed(); 
}
```

---

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);

    }
}
```

---

**In kotlin**

```
 private var exit = false

 if (exit) {
        onBackPressed()
         }
```

---

```
 override fun onBackPressed(){
           if (exit){
               finish() // finish activity
           }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            exit = true
            Handler().postDelayed({ exit = false }, 3 * 1000)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question, but this is the easiest way to do what you want.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   ++k; //initialise k when you first start your activity.
   if(k==1){
      //do whatever you want to do on first click for example:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Press back one more time to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else{
      //do whatever you want to do on the click after the first for example:
      finish(); 
   }
}
```

I know this isn't the best method, but it works fine!

Comment: This is not the general behaviour of "clicking back button twice to exit". Like BruceHill's comment on accepted answer points out, your answer doesn't handle time issue too

Comment: but with this you can click back, it will show the message, and then you can wait a little longer, go back again and it will close the app, and it will not handle the behaviour of double back timing

Answer (score 4):

I would normally add a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow this.
So here's my two cents:

In Kotlin you can use coroutines to delay the setting to false:

```
private var doubleBackPressed = false
private var toast : Toast ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    toast = Toast.maketext(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackPressed) {
        toast?.cancel()
        super.onBackPressed()
        return
    }
    this.doubleBackPressed = true
    toast?.show()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        doubleBackPressed = false
    }
}
```

You will have to import:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
```

Comment: This is a nice approach with the use of coroutines, but as at 2022, super.onBackPressed has been deprecated. Hence this answer requires modification. Call finishActivity() to exit instead.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose I have implemented the following function:

```
private long onRecentBackPressedTime;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - onRecentBackPressedTime > 2000) {
       onRecentBackPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Please press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;
     }
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly better method than [Zefnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22332291/5082855) I think. Call System.currentTimeMillis() just one time and omit `return;` :

```
long previousTime;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (2000 + previousTime > (previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis())) 
    { 
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This also helps when you have previous stack activity stored in stack.

I have modified Sudheesh's answer

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        //super.onBackPressed();

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need, I mean when we want to show this toast, **when there is only one activity in the stack and user pressing back** from this last activity of the stack.

```
var exitOpened=false // Declare it globaly
```

and in `onBackPressed` method change it like:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (isTaskRoot && !exitOpened)
        {
            exitOpened=true
            toast("Please press back again to exit")
            return
        }
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

Here, `isTaskRoot` will return true if the current activity is the **root activity(first activity)** of the stack and false if it is not.

You can check the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How does this even handle the double press scenario? As soon as I hit back, this launches an activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full working code. And also don't forget to remove the callbacks so that it don't cause a memory leak in the app. :)

```
private boolean backPressedOnce = false;
private Handler statusUpdateHandler;
private Runnable statusUpdateRunnable;

public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressedOnce) {
            finish();
        }

        backPressedOnce = true;
        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        statusUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                backPressedOnce = false;
                toast.cancel();  //Removes the toast after the exit.
            }
        };

        statusUpdateHandler.postDelayed(statusUpdateRunnable, 2000);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (statusUpdateHandler != null) {
        statusUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(statusUpdateRunnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the activity whose is having **Navigation Drawer**, Use the following code for OnBackPressed()

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==0) {
                    finishAffinity();
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
                return;
            }

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==0) {
                this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    }
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I have generalized write the code for N tap counts. The code is similarly written for the Enable Developer option in android device phone. Even you can use this to enable features while developer testing the app.

```
 private Handler tapHandler;
 private Runnable tapRunnable;
 private int mTapCount = 0;
 private int milSecDealy = 2000;

onCreate(){
 ...
tapHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

 }
```

*Call **askToExit()** on backpress or logout option.*

```
private void askToExit() {
   if (mTapCount >= 2) {
    releaseTapValues();
    /* ========= Exit = TRUE  =========  */
   }

   mTapCount++;
   validateTapCount();
  }


  /* Check with null to avoid create multiple instances of the runnable */
  private void validateTapCount() {
   if (tapRunnable == null) {
    tapRunnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      releaseTapValues();
      /* ========= Exit = FALSE  =========  */
     }
    };
    tapHandler.postDelayed(tapRunnable, milSecDealy);
   }
  }

  private void releaseTapValues() {
   /* Relase the value  */
   if (tapHandler != null) {
    tapHandler.removeCallbacks(tapRunnable);
    tapRunnable = null; /* release the object */
    mTapCount = 0; /* release the value */
   }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   releaseTapValues();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExitApp {

    private static long lastClickTime;

    public static void now(Activity ctx, @StringRes int message) {
        now(ctx, ctx.getString(message), 2500);
    }

    public static void now(Activity ctx, @StringRes int message, long time) {
        now(ctx, ctx.getString(message), time);
    }

    public static void now(Activity ctx, String message, long time) {
        if (ctx != null && !message.isEmpty() && time != 0) {
            if (lastClickTime + time > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                ctx.finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*use to* in event `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   ExitApp.now(this,"Press again for close");
}
```

or `ExitApp.now(this,R.string.double_back_pressed)`

for change seconds need for close, specified miliseconds

`ExitApp.now(this,R.string.double_back_pressed,5000)`

Answer (score 2):

When HomeActivity contain navigation drawer and double backPressed() funtion to exit app.
(Don't forget to initilize global variable     boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;)
new handler after 2 sec set doubleBackPressedOnce variable to false

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return;
        } else {
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most modern applications use just one activity and multiple fragments. So if you're using Navigation Components and needs to call implement that from the home fragment, here is the solution.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val callback: OnBackPressedCallback = object :
    OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (doubleBackPressed) {
                activity.finishAffinity()
            }
            doubleBackPressed = true
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed(Runnable {doubleBackPressed = false},
                2000)
            }
        }
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**I think this is the easiest method**

```
private static long exit;
@override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    exit = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: onBackpressed is already deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;

    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.photo_album_parent_view), "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Improvements in Sudheesh B Nair's answer, i have noticed it will wait for handler even while pressing back twice immediately, so cancel handler as shown below. I have cancled toast also to prevent it to display after app exit.

```
 boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        Handler myHandler;
        Runnable myRunnable;
        Toast myToast;

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                myToast.cancel();
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            myToast.show();

            myHandler = new Handler();

            myRunnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                }
            };
            myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same of the accepted and most voted response but this snipped used Snackbar instead of Toast.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Snackbar.make(content, "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've depend on `Snackbar#isShown()` for better `UX`.

```
private Snackbar exitSnackBar;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isNavDrawerOpen()) {
        closeNavDrawer();
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        if (exitSnackBar != null && exitSnackBar.isShown()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            exitSnackBar = Snackbar.make(
                    binding.getRoot(),
                    R.string.navigation_exit,
                    2000
            );
            exitSnackBar.show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, Snackbar is the better option then Toast to display the quit action. Here is the method with snackbar that works.

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Snackbar.make(this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way... using the *CountDownTimer* method

```
private boolean exit = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin on the back press to exit app you can use:

Define a global variable:

```
private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
```

Override onBackPressed:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed()
            return
        }

        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        Handler().postDelayed({
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }, 2000)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution with Toast

> In Java

```
private Toast exitToast;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exitToast == null || exitToast.getView() == null || exitToast.getView().getWindowToken() == null) {
        exitToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        exitToast.show();
    } else {
        exitToast.cancel();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

> In Kotlin

```
private var exitToast: Toast? = null

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (exitToast == null || exitToast!!.view == null || exitToast!!.view.windowToken == null) {
        exitToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        exitToast!!.show()
    } else {
        exitToast!!.cancel()
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23126219/1039555), only 5 years late. Perhaps you wanted to upvote and comment on my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

The unique thing about this solution is the behaviour; in that a non double tap will show the toast and a successful double tap will show no toast while closing the app.
The only disadvantage being the the showing of the toast will have a 650 millisecond delay. I believe this is the best solution with the best behaviour as logic dictates that it would be impossible to have this behaviour without such a delay

```
//App Closing Vars
private var doubleBackPressedInterval: Long = 650
private var doubleTap = false
private var pressCount = 0
private var timeLimit: Long = 0

override fun onBackPressed() {
    pressCount++
    if(pressCount == 1) {
        timeLimit = System.currentTimeMillis() + doubleBackPressedInterval
        if(!doubleTap) {
            showExitInstructions()
        }
    }
    if(pressCount == 2) {
        if(timeLimit > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            doubleTap = true
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
        else {
            showExitInstructions()
        }
        pressCount = 1
        timeLimit = System.currentTimeMillis() + doubleBackPressedInterval
    }
}

private fun showExitInstructions() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        if(!doubleTap) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Try Agian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }, doubleBackPressedInterval)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16098431/11579741) answer is easy to use but we need to double-tap to exit. I just modify the answer ,

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ++k;
    if(k==1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back one more time to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                --k;
            }
        },1000);
    }else{
        //do whatever you want to do on the click after the first for example:
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After having had to implement the same things many times, decided its about time someone built a simple to use library. And that is [`DoubleBackPress Android library`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress). The `README` explains all the APIs provided along with Examples (like [ToastDisplay + Exit Activity](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/kaushikthedeveloper/doublebackpress/example/ToastDisplayActivity.java)), but a short rundown of the steps here.

---

To get going, start by adding the `dependency` to your application :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:double-back-press:0.0.1'
}
```

---

Next, create a `DoubleBackPress` object in your `Activity` which provides the required behaviour.

```
DoubleBackPress doubleBackPress = new DoubleBackPress();
doubleBackPress.setDoublePressDuration(3000);           // msec
```

Then create a `Toast` that needs to be shown upon the *First Back Press*. Here, you can create your own `Toast`, or go with `Standard Toast` provided in the `library`. Doing so here by the later option.

```
FirstBackPressAction firstBackPressAction = new ToastDisplay().standard(this);
doubleBackPress.setFirstBackPressAction(firstBackPressAction);   // set the action
```

Now, define what should happen when your Second Back Press happens. Here, we are closing the Activity.

```
DoubleBackPressAction doubleBackPressAction = new DoubleBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
};
```

Finally, override your back press behaviour with the `DoubleBackPress` behaviour.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackPress.onBackPressed();
}
```

[Example GIF of similar behavioural requirements](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress#ToastDisplayExample)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
    private static long back_pressed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even make it more simple, and without using a hander, only do this =)

```
Long firstClick = 1L;
Long secondClick = 0L;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
secondClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((secondClick - firstClick) / 1000 < 2) {
          super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
          firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the visibility of a Toast, so you don't need that Handler/postDelayed ultra solution.

```
Toast doubleBackButtonToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    doubleBackButtonToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Double tap back to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackButtonToast.getView().isShown()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    doubleBackButtonToast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
private long mBackPressed;
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstpageActivity.this,
                        HomepageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                return;
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Tap back button twice  to go Home.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this :

```
 int oddeven = 0;
 long backBtnPressed1;
 long backBtnPressed2;
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     oddeven++;
     if(oddeven%2==0){
         backBtnPressed2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if(backBtnPressed2-backBtnPressed1<2000) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
         }
     }
     else if(oddeven%2==1) { 
         backBtnPressed1 = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        //  Insert toast back button here
     }
 }
```

Comment: il try this I guess this is the LEAK-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using RxJava:

```
override fun onCreate(...) {
    backPresses.timeInterval(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .skip(1) //Skip initial event; delay will be 0.
            .onMain()
            .subscribe {
                if (it.time() < 7000) super.onBackPressed() //7000 is the duration of a Toast with length LENGTH_LONG.
            }.addTo(compositeDisposable)

    backPresses.throttleFirst(7000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit.", LENGTH_LONG).show() }
            .addTo(compositeDisposable)
}

override fun onBackPressed() = backPresses.onNext(Unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Back when Button pressed 2 times

```
public void click(View view){
    if (isBackActivated) {
        this.finish();
    }
    if (!isBackActivated) {
        isBackActivated = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isBackActivated = false;  // setting isBackActivated after 2 second
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to create a utils class for this, so any activity or fragment can implement this to be simpler.

The code was written with Kotlin & has Java-interop as well.

I'm using coroutine to delay and reset the flag variable. But you can modify it to your needs.

**Additional files**: `SafeToast.kt`

```
lateinit var toast: Toast

fun Context.safeToast(msg: String, length: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG, action: (Context) -> Toast = default) {
    toast = SafeToast.makeText(this@safeToast, msg, length).apply {
        // do anything new here
        action(this@safeToast)
        show()
    }
}

fun Context.toastSpammable(msg: String) {
    cancel()
    safeToast(msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
}

fun Fragment.toastSpammable(msg: String) {
    cancel()
    requireContext().safeToast(msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
}

private val default: (Context) -> Toast = { it -> SafeToast.makeText(it, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) }

private fun cancel() {
    if (::toast.isInitialized) toast.cancel()
}
```

**ActivityUtils.kt**

```
@file:JvmMultifileClass
@file:JvmName("ActivityUtils")
package your.company.com

import android.app.Activity
import your.company.com.R
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


private var backButtonPressedTwice = false

fun Activity.onBackPressedTwiceFinish() {
    onBackPressedTwiceFinish(getString(R.string.msg_back_pressed_to_exit), 2000)
}

fun Activity.onBackPressedTwiceFinish(@StringRes message: Int, time: Long) {
    onBackPressedTwiceFinish(getString(message), time)
}

fun Activity.onBackPressedTwiceFinish(message: String, time: Long) {
    if (backButtonPressedTwice) {
        onBackPressed()
    } else {
        backButtonPressedTwice = true
        toastSpammable(message)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(time)
            backButtonPressedTwice = false
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage in Kotlin**

```
// ActivityA.kt
override fun onBackPressed() {
    onBackPressedTwiceFinish()
}
```

**Usage in Java**

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    ActivityUtils.onBackPressedTwiceFinish()
}
```

This code was inspired by @webserveis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517883/3763032)