# Disable input when enter key pressed multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make so that when the enter key is pressed multiple times, the site only detects the input once? I have a small bug which occurs whenever the user double taps the enter key in an input box, so what I want to do is only accept the input press once. Thank you so much in advance!!

```
  $('#search_list').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {


   }    
}
```

Comment: Do you have `<form>` element as parent of `#search_list` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent repeatedly enter pressing by this way:

```
var enterPressed = false;

$('#search_list').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {
       if( ! enterPressed){
         // do some processing
         return;
       }
      enterPressed = true;
      setTimeout(function(){
         enterPressed = false;
      }, 1000);

   }    
}
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578600/2407522).

Answer (score 0):

```
var enterPressed = false;

$('#search_list').keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.which == '13') {
       if( ! enterPressed){
         // do some processing

          enterPressed = true;
          setTimeout(function(){
            enterPressed = false;
          }, 1000);

        }


   }    
}
```

I think this way is better.