# BackButton not working properly

Tags: android

i have application which starts with an animation and then we move to another(P1 )activity.
But if i press back button from from p1 then i go back to the animation(LoadActivity) and if i press back button now then i should go to application manager but instead i go back to P1 activity like there is a loop from p1 to LoadActivity and from LoadActivity to P1

LoadActivity.java

```
public class LoadActivity extends Activity  {
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
    ImageView im;
    Animation rotate;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.load_icon);
        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.load_page);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        im.startAnimation(rotate);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    P1.class);
            startActivity(nextPageIntent);

        }
    };

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
}

    public void onBackPressed() {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mRunnable);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());


        }
```

P1.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p1);
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

             context=this;
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_inflate_land,null);
            RelativeLayout f=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.iv_p1);
            f.addView(view);
        }
        else {

             context=this;
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_inflate,null);
            RelativeLayout f=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.iv_p1);
            f.addView(view);
        }



        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.let_start_p2);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), P2.class);
                startActivity(nextPageIntent);
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoadActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextPageIntent);
        }
```

Comment: try to finish your activity in onBackPressed() after call LoadActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to replace this code :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoadActivity.class);
  startActivity(nextPageIntent);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: This helped but now when i press backbutton in P1 then it comes to LosdActivity but now if i again press the back button it again restarts Loadactivity and now it i press backbutton then it exits

Comment: So i need to press backkbutton twice to exit

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity

Comment: can you please let me know why again start P1 from LoadActivity in handler ?

Comment: Bcoz i have to go to P1 once the animation is finished that is user requirement

Comment: No Sathish the problem still persist

Comment: Okay so when your animation is over you again goto P1 and back pressed again came to LoadActivity so my question when you exit from LoadActivity ?

Comment: then according to requirement the application is be killed but according to my code it is restarting LoadActivity and then if backbutton is pressed then the application is finished so in a nutshell we need to press backbutton twice in order to exit the application when in LoadActivity

Comment: can you please override onBackPressed() in LoadActvity and first line mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable); and second line super.onBackPressed(); and let me is it working or not ?

Comment: can you please post code in you question what have you done ?