# Detect dismiss keyboard event in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a edittext which needs to function like the textfield in iOS. When I click on it, should become editable else it should be disabled. Let's say the user wants to edit a certain value and when he presses the back button, along with the keyboard dismiss I want the edittext to become disabled to edit.

All I am using is the setCursorVisible(true) and setCursorVisible(false) method. I did try using keyCode events but they aren't helping. This is what I have tried up until now:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
// Had the InputMethodManager service here..
        if(imm.isAcceptingText())
        {
           Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"back pressed called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Also tried overriding keyDown event.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

            Log.d("123","called,called");
            return  true;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about [creating a subclass of EditText and overriding its onKeyPreIme method](https://boltingupandroid.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/detect-dismissal-of-the-soft-keyboard/)

```
/**
 * This class overrides the onKeyPreIme method to dispatch a key event if the
 * KeyEvent passed to onKeyPreIme has a key code of KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
 * This allows key event listeners to detect that the soft keyboard was
 * dismissed.
 *
 */
public class ExtendedEditText extends EditText {

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public ExtendedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // User has pressed Back key. So hide the keyboard
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // TODO: Hide your view as you do it in your activity
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Did try to use this...but the activity gets finished as soon as back is pressed.I want the activity to get finished on the second time I press back..On first backpress,Dismiss keyboard and setCursorVisible(false) is what i am expecting.

Comment: You mean like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity ?

Comment: @Slartibastfast No no not in that manner...may be your solution will work..trying it..I will have to override dispatchEvent in the activity and detect the event there?..right?

Comment: @Slartibastfast My requirement is that after editting when I press back button the edittext should get disabled.

Comment: Did return true instead of return false, and it solved my problem of activity getting finished. Nice solution..!!!

Comment: Add  `if (event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == ACTION_UP) {` to call the function only once