# press back again to exit

Tags: android, toast

I have an app and I want to do that when user touch back button a Toast show "press back again to exit" but i have problem with this part. on this code, when touch back button app completely finish without toast and touch back button again. Please help me.

```
   public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(key == 1){
            key =0;
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "press back Button again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        key++;
        }
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
    }
}, 2000);
}
```

you can go though this link
[Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity)

same question

Comment: I already mentioned link of this code in my answer.

Comment: oops i didnt see first commit. :-)

Comment: Thanks Dear avi, I saw link but i likewise have problem and now with your help i can do that, problem return to  doubleBackToExitPressedOnce with this code but now solved. thanks.

Comment: @saeidmirzapour I wonder same "doubleBackToExitPressedOnce" post link i mentioned first and answer is ignored. Anyway thank you.

Comment: gr8. problem solved :-)

Comment: @avi Excuse me, what is do "2000" in this code?

Comment: oh, its for Toast, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to write code inside `onBackPressed()` method. Try this code:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if(key == 1){
            key =0;
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "press back Button again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        key++;
        }
}
```

I recommend you to follow this post: [Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity)

Comment: Thanks Dear Anand, but this code, likewise I have problem.

Comment: I hope it is solved now?

Comment: make key global and initialize it with 0.