# How to close activity in android?

Tags: android

I have a menu button on the bottom and I have display menu icons from another activity like MenuTask.

But how to close that MenuTask activity if the user clicks again in the menu?

```
imgMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (key == 0) {
            // I want to show menu here
            key = 1;    
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuAction.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            setResult(0);
        } else if (key == 1) {
            // I want to Delete menu here
            key = 0;
            //onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Note: I think if i click second time , button could not fire. it means else part not execute.
[image]

**Problem:**
I have Clicked, right top menu button and open new activity menu action. but if i want to click again same menu button, i want to disappers that menu action. but menu button could not clicked.

**How to make MenuButton Clickable? any idea? any other menthod? But when i click mobile backbutton menuaction layout disappeared.**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is not best way. You must use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

If you want only kill activity `MenuAction.this.finish();`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
  }

  this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
  Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  // handler to delay
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

you can go though this link [Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity)

same question