# Close app if double back pressed using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im combining replace with addtobackstack for new fragments added the activity.
like so:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, searchFragment,"Frag_Search").addToBackStack("searchFragment").commit();
```

When the user back presses twice, i would like the app to exit

I tried some answers here:
[Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity)
but the don't close the app, just keeps removing the last fragment.

Comment: Follow the link you posted, but instead of calling super.onBackPressed call finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exit from your fragment by calling getActivity().finish()

Answer (score 0):

You may have to empty the backstack first by doing something like this

```
private void popEveryFragment() {
    // Clear all back stack.
    int backStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {

        // Get the back stack fragment id.
        int backStackId = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();

        mFragmentManager.popBackStack(backStackId, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to set the code of the **top answer** from this question [Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity) inside your main activity.

Comment: yes using top answer, as per the comment from Gabe to this question, if i call finish() instead of super.OnBackPressed t kind of works...

Comment: Can you post your code of the MainActivity and Fragment to can help you.