# How to enable exit only backpress activity twice in Android?

Tags: android

I have a Wordpress based news application. To make things faster I have bought a template which served most of needs. But in the app when i press back button on home or any first level screens it exits from the app.

How can I implement Exit only when the user presses back button twice?

Comment: Override the `onBackPressed` method.

Comment: so, you're developing an Android App as a WebView on your site?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; // # milliseconds, desired time passed between two back presses.
    private long mBackPressed;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
        { 
            super.onBackPressed(); 
            return;
        }
        else { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

        mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Comment: Same comment as other post. Don't duplicate answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22332291/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 this is the right link . I would appreciate if OP would google once before asking here . Not trying to discourage but it's always better to look for answers before posting

Comment: @user3164647 Yes, that's why when you post a question here it gives you suggestions for other questions with similar titles.

Answer (score 0):

After having to implement the same behaviour many times, decided to come up with an android library for it. [`DoubleBackPress Android Library`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress), takes care of all the hassle, and provides easy templates to work with.

[Example GIF of similar behavioural requirements](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress#ToastDisplayExample).

First, add the dependecy to your application :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:double-back-press:0.0.1'
}
```

Now, the implementation :

```
// set the Action to occur on DoubleBackPress
DoubleBackPressAction doubleBackPressAction = new DoubleBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        // TODO : your code to exit the application
    }
};

// setup DoubleBackPress behaviour
DoubleBackPress doubleBackPress = new DoubleBackPress()
        .withDoublePressDuration(3000)                         //msec - timeout
        .withDoubleBackPressAction(doubleBackPressAction);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackPress.onBackPressed();
}
```