# Android back button app is not closing

Tags: android, android-activity

i am using the below code for back button but it cant work it does not exit the app if i am pressing the back button of userdevice

```
  private Boolean exit = false;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (exit) {
                this.finish(); // finish activity
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 3 * 1000);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity)

Comment: you have to press back button 2 time with in 3 sec

Comment: You probably have other activities, closing one of them doesn't mean closing an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Code Like This.

```
 private Boolean exit = false;

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (exit) {
                    this.finishAffinity();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    exit = true;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            exit = false;
                        }
                    }, 3 * 1000);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

private Boolean exit = false;

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (exit) {
                this.finishAffinity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 3 * 1000);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {

            //Add Snhackbar or Toast, whatever you want
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            moveTaskToBack(true);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Use `finishAffinity()` instead.

```
  boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

  public void onBackPressed(){
        if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
        {
            finishAffinity();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

            }
        },3500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

keep a boolean toClose=false;
and in onBackPressed() method use this code

```
if (toClose)
    super.onBackPressed();
    else
    {
        toClose=true;
        Utils.showToast(context,getString(R.string.back_again));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toClose=false;
            }
        },2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you 
    Define this it globally

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitProceed = false;
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitProceed) {
      finish();
      return;
    }
    doubleBackToExitProceed = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitProceed = false;
      }
    }, 2000);// time in milliseconds.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to close the app on pressing back button.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```